# Covering the Cake During Kiddush

Tags: shabbat, kiddush, food

Many times there is cake, cookies or various other foods out on the table during Kiddush. Is it necessary to cover them (as I sometimes see people do)? Would it make a difference if the cake is going to be eaten in lieu of Grape Juice?

(just read: [What sort of covering is required for Challa and cake while making Kiddush?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5898/what-sort-of-covering-is-required-for-challa-and-cake-while-making-kiddush))

Comment: see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/16387/759

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The reason of the "shame" of the
>   challos, applies to mezonos as well,
>   since ordinarily the blessing of
>   mezonos is recited before the blessing
>   of ha-gafen. Indeed, some poskim rule
>   that cakes and pastries should be
>   covered during the recital of the
>   morning Kiddush.(Kitzur Shulchan Aruch
>   55:5; Teshuvos Levushei Mordechai O.C.
>   kamma, 46. Even according to this
>   view, however, only the person making
>   Kiddush [and others who are partaking
>   of the wine] needs to cover his
>   mezonos items. All other participants
>   do not need to cover their mezonos,
>   since they are not "shaming" the
>   mezonos by listening to Kiddush; Harav
>   S.Z. Auerbach (Shemiras Shabbos
>   K'hilchasah 47, note 125).
>
> But not all poskim agree. Eishel
>   Avraham Orach Chaim 182 holds that
>   mezonos items do not need to be
>   covered during Kiddush because only
>   challos - which can be used for
>   Kiddush and are being bypassed in
>   favor of wine - are being "shamed."
>   Mezonos items, however, are generally
>   not eligible to have Kiddush recited
>   over them, so they cannot be "shamed"
>   by the wine taking precedence over
>   them.(Ta'amei ha-Minhagim, 365,
>   Kuntress Acharon; Az Nidberu 2:)

http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5765/kisisa.html

Comment: Any idea which _Eshel Avraham_ this is?

Comment: Anything on the second part "in lieu..."

Comment: @msh210: Eshel Avraham is the Pri Megadim's commentary on the Magen Avraham.

Comment: @Chanoch I think he means where in the Eshel Avraham.

Comment: So on a Saturday night Yom Tov you don't have to cover the Challot according to those who say you can't say Yaknehaz on the bread because of the Havdallah component?

Comment: @Chanoch Eshel Avraham is also a different commentary to Orach Chaim by [Avraham of Butchastch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_David_ben_Asher_Anshel_Buczacz).

Answer (score 2):

Hacham Ovadia writes in Hazon Ovadia that one should cover the cake as well before Kidush.

Comment: makor for this?