# PTIJ: Gingerbread man making Kiddush

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

There is a Halacha to cover bread and Mezonos during Kiddush (related question: [Covering the Cake During Kiddush](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5918/covering-the-cake-during-kiddush)). How does the [Gingerbread man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gingerbread_Man) make Kiddush if he is Mezonos? Does he need to cover himself completely first?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on if he’s milchig or parve. Assuming for shabbos you are serving meat, as is the custom, if he is milchig, you need to cover him lest there be a mixup. Many are machmir to do something to to make it clear he is milchig, like paint a milk carton in his hand.

Now what if he is DE? Ask [another question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=Dairy%20equipment). Recently the והכג VHKG (Va’ad HaKasherus Gingerbreadland) started using the KG-DE and labelled some items that were previously KG-D as KG-DE. If you have an existing package labelled KG-D, check the lot number and call 1-866-555-FAST.

Answer (score 3):

It could be the halacha of covering mezonos is only when you plan on eating from the mezonos after kiddush. But if you never plan on eating the mezonos, there might not be a reason to cover it. The gingerbread man ain't planning on eating himself, so he wouldn't have to cover himself during kiddush.
However you can cler that he should need to cover himself because he's naked and you can't say a bracha in front of erva. It could be that his skin isn't considered an erva. Just like there's no problem of erva by naked animals and by babies.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to cover the Challa or cake or the Gingerbread Man when a Gingerbread Man makes Kiddush. The reason it is covered is in order not to embarrass the Challa and cake. However a Gingerbread Man only knows how to run, and does not know how to make Kiddush. When he says the words he will be embarrased, not the Challa and cake. (Hilchos Purim 125:16)