# If I want to keep a bentcher in my pocket wrapped, can I use a clear sandwich bag?

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, see-sight-vision-blind, protective-casing

I carry a mincha/maariv bentcher in my pocket, and I keep it wrapped in a paper covering in case I walk into the bathroom. (I know that some hold that bathrooms today don't need a double covering, but I prefer to keep a double covering)

My question is - does the covering need to be opaque, or can I use for example a clear polyethylene sandwich bag?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/21951/bringing-wallet-with-benscher-into-bathroom

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5898/759

Comment: Victor Grazi, welcome to Mi Yodeya and thank you for contributing this interesting question! Remember that anything you read here should be treated like information from a group of friends and is not a substitute for qualified rabbinic advice in actual circumstances. That said, I look forward to seeing you around.

Comment: Thanks, of course I will keep that in mind. It would be great if responders could quote a source for easy checking

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Mishnah Brurah ([40:7](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14170&st=&pgnum=136)) says that it's okay for one of the two coverings to be clear, but not both of them.